# wait for all child processes in background to complete and exit with return code of last child process

Tags: linux, shell, background, pid, exit-code

I have a shell like this

```
 middle.ksh <parameter>
     inner1.ksh <para> > Log 2>&1 &
     p1=$!

     inner2.ksh <para> > log 2>&1 &
     p2=$!
     inner3.ksh <para> > log 2>&1 &
     p2=$!
     sleep nnn 
      inner4.ksh <para> > log 2>&1 & /#  L1last process fired 
     p2=$!
     rc=$? /#  I am checking the rc for the last process 
     wait
```

I would like to do something like this
--find out if ALL the processes fired in background have completed.
-- when all have completed I'd like middle.ksh to exit with the return code of last child process - viz inner4.ksh in above e.g. In other words - I want to say middle.ksh ran fine if all processes it fired inside it succeeded ( inner 1..4) && inner4.ksh succeeded. 
If inner4.ksh failed - middle.ksh has failed.
Now I can collect each PID and say `wait p1 p2 p3 etc`
Problem is all these child shells are written dynamically in the wrapper ( middle.ksh), so I dont know how many inner.ksh there will be can be 10 -can  be 100
Can it be done easily - or am I missing something .
ty

Answer (score 1):

It's a little convoluted, but...

```
{
     inner1.ksh ... &
     inner2.ksh ... &
     # and all the rest but one of the inner*.ksh jobs
     wait
} &
all_but_one_pid=$!
innerN.ksh ... &
last_pid=$!
wait $all_but_one_pid
wait $last_pid
```

`middle.ksh` has two processes: one which runs all but one of the `inner*.ksh` jobs in parallel and exits when they are all done, and a second which runs the last `inner*.ksh` job. Once those two jobs are finished, you simply `wait` on the first, then `wait` on the second. If `wait $last_pid` is the last command in `middle.ksh`, you can simply exit; the exit status of the `wait` (which is the exit status of the single `inner*.ksh` job it waits on) will be the exit status of `middle.ksh`. Otherwise, just put `rc=$?` immediately after that `wait` to save the return value for later when `middle.ksh` exits.